Proceed with bulk insert operation on duplicate key error, but SHOW which documents are dupes - if possible by updating document
I receive many documents from an API that I want to write to my database. Unfortunately, the APIs paging is not great and often returns the same documents that have already been inserted. I therefore want to bulk-insert the documents I receive WITHOUT cancelling the whole operation, by just skipping the duplicate ones.
From another answer on this site, this seems easily doable by changing the "ordered" flag to false. However, I do want to know which documents would have been duplicates. How do I print/output/save attempts at inserting duplicate documents (ie duplicate key errors), while not impacting the actual insert operation (i.e. not having to switch to insertOne or something)?
I tried accessing PyMongo's .inserted_ids of the result of the insert_many operation, however, the insert_many operation raises an Exception even if ordered=False, so I cannot access the property.
Is there perhaps a better way of upserting those documents, by for example appending a string (my current search query + date) to an array field in the document?
